# Force update on FabricJS Canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, fabricjs

I have a legacy web app that uses fabricJS(v1.4.4)'s canvas in order to provide a web Paint-alike editor for childrens where they can choose between a gallery of backgrounds and stamps to create images and develop technology knowledge.

It had been working fine until last Chrome update (v83), where that objects (backgrounds and stamps) only appear when i click anywhere on the canvas.

I was looking a way of forcing the canvas to refresh itself, but most of the alternatives uses functions (such as requestRenderAll or dirty) that seem are not available in my version.

This is the code for setting the background:

```
(a.prototype.setBackgroundImage = function (a) {
            var b = this;
            return fabric.Image.fromURL(a, function (a) {
                return (
                    (a.left = 0),
                    (a.top = 0),
                    b.clear(),
                    (b.state = { historial: [], index: 0, ignore: !1 }),
                    null != b.backgroundObject && b.canvas.remove(b.backgroundObject),
                    (a.selectable = !1),
                    (a.isBackground = !0),
                    b.canvas.add(a),
                    (a = b.canvas.item(b.canvas._objects.length - 1)),
                    a.sendToBack(),
                    a.setCoords(),
                    (b.backgroundObject = a),
                    b.canvas.renderAll()
                );
            });
        }),
```

And here is the funcion that paste stamps:

```
(a.prototype.insertImage = function (a, b, c) {
            var d;
            return (
                null == c && (c = null),
                this.setTool("select"),
                null === c
                    ? ((c = {}),
                      (c.width = this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width),
                      (c.height = this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width),
                      this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width < 15 && ((c.width = 15), (c.height = 15)),
                      (c.width = 90),
                      (c.height = 90),
                      (d = new fabric.Image(a, { left: b.x, top: b.y, width: c.width, height: c.height })),
                      this.canvas.add(d),
                      void 0)
                    : ((d = new fabric.Image(a, { left: b.x, top: b.y, width: c.width, height: c.height })), this.canvas.add(d))
            );
        }),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call `canvas.renderAll()` after image is loaded.

Comment: Thank you @Durga.

It is called into the **setBackgroundImage** and didn't work. I test putting it twice and it works, but I didn't in the **insertImage** function when I added it before the void.

Comment: No need to call twice. Loading the image is asynchronous, so after loaded if you call renderAll that is enough. You can use fabric.image.fromurl in the callback call renderAll.